# How to add border of canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, border

I want to add the border off canvas using C# not XAML

How can i achieve it?

Answer (score 18):

I think you're better off by placing the canvas inside a border, then specify the border thickness in your code-behind.  In your code you could then programmatically turn the border on and off.

XAML:

```
<Border x:Name="CanvasBorder" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Canvas>
        <!--Items here-->
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```

Code-behind:

```
// Turn on border
CanvasBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(1);

// Turn off border
CanvasBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simple create border canvas with `DataBinding` on her `Width` to `MainCanvas.ActualWidth` and `Height` to `MainCanvas.ActualHeight`